# Saturated set and union of prime ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> A multiplicatively closed subset $S$ of $A$ is said to be saturated if $xy \in S $ is equivalent to $x\in S $ and $ y\in S$ . Prove that $S$ is saturated iff $A\setminus S$ is a union of prime ideals.

This question is from my commutative algebra quiz which is over now.

Attempt: Assuming $A\setminus S$ to be union of prime ideals I have proved that S must be saturated.

Conversely, given $S$ is saturated, I tried by Assuming that in $A \setminus S$ there exists an ideal $I$ which is not prime. So, $I$ has element $xy$, such that both $x$ and $y$ are not in $I$. Now, I need to somehow get a contradiction to the fact that $S$ is  saturated, which I am unable to.

Can you please guide with this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is important to use correct notation. It is $A\setminus S$, not $A/S$, the complement of $S$. It is sufficient to prove that if $S$ is saturated then every element $x\in A\setminus S$ is contained in a prime ideal which is contained in $A\setminus S$. So let $x\in A\setminus S$. Let:

$\mathcal{F}=\{I\subseteq A|\  I\text{ is an ideal, $x \in I$ and $I\cap S=\emptyset$}\}$

Since $S$ is saturated, the ideal $Ax=\{ax: a\in A\}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$, and so $\mathcal{F}$ is not empty. Using Zorn's lemma it is very easy to show that $\mathcal{F}$ contains a maximal element with respect to inclusion. So let $P\in\mathcal{F}$ be a maximal element. We will show it is prime.

Suppose $y,z\notin P$ satisfy $yz\in P$. The ideal $P+Ay$ properly contains $P$, and so by maximality it follows that $P+Ay$ intersects $S$. So there are $p_1\in P, a_1\in A$ such that $p_1+a_1y\in S$. Similarly, there are $p_2\in P, a_2\in A$ such that $p_2+a_2z\in S$. Since $S$ is multiplicative, the product $(p_1+a_1y)(p_2+a_2z)$ belongs to $S$ as well. But:

$(p_1+a_1y)(p_2+a_2z)=p_1p_2+p_2a_1y+p_1a_2z+a_1a_2yz\in P$

Which is a contradiction to $P\cap S=\emptyset$.

Comment: How does S being saturated implies that ideal Ax belongs to F? Can you please elaborate? ( 5th line of your answer)

Comment: @Evan Because if we had $Ax\cap S\ne\emptyset$ then it would mean there is some $a\in A$ such that $ax\in S$. But since $S$ is saturated, this implies $a,x\in S$. This contradicts the assumption that $x\notin S$.